# using get token in php registration

Tags: php, validation, token

Ok when I get it prevents my validation(server side php) from working.

I have commented out the get token and my code works well, is there a reason for this?

**code**

```
    <?php
require_once 'core/init.php';

if(Input::exists()) {

    echo 'i have been run';

    it works will i comment this line out //if(Token::check(Input::get('token'))) {
    $validate = new Validate();
    $validation = $validate->check($_POST, array(
        'username' => array(
            'required' => true,
            'min' => 2,
            'max' => 20,
            'unique' => 'users'
        ),
        'password' => array(
            'required' => true,
            'min' => 6
        ),  
        'password_again' => array(
            'required' => true,
            'matches' => 'password'
        ),  
        'name' => array(
            'required' => true,
            'min' => 2,
            'max' => 50
        )
    ));

    if($validation->passed()) {
        $user = new User();

        $salt = Hash::salt(32);

        try {

            $user->create(array(
                'username' => Input::get('username'),
                'password' => Hash::make(Input::get('password'), $salt),
                'salt' => $salt,
                'name' => Input::get('name'),
                'joined' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                'group' => 1
            ));

            Session::flash('home', 'You have been registered  and now can log in!');
            header('Location: index.php');

        } catch(Exception $e) {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    } else {
            foreach($validation->errors() as $error) {
                echo $error, '<br>';
            }
        }
    }   
//}
?>
```

**Token.php**

```
    <?php
class Token {
    public static function generate() {
        return Session::put(Config::get('session/token_name'), md5(uniqid()));
    }

    public static function check($token) {
        $tokenName = Config::get('session/token_name');

        if(Session::exists($tokenName) && $token === Session::get($tokenName)) {
            Session::delete($tokenName);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

**Hash.php**

```
    <?php
class Hash {
    public static function make($string, $salt = '') {
        return hash('sha256', $string . $salt);
    }

    public static function salt($length) {
        return mcrypt_create_iv($length);
    }

    public static function unique() {
        return self::make(uniqid());
    }
}
```

Comment: So what is `Token::check(Input::get('token')`? Is this your own Class or is it a platform of some sort?

Comment: good point @putvande  i have now amended my question with my token

Comment: is Token::check(Input::get('token')) returning false?  if so you may want to throw some debugging in there to make sure that Input::get('token') and Session::get($tokenName) are returning what you expect them to return

Comment: @armsteady ok, good advise i will give it a go.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using Laravel.  If that's the case, there's already a CSRF filter that I think is accomplishing what you're trying to do.

See: /app/filters.php

```
Route::filter('csrf', function()
{
    if (Session::token() != Input::get('_token') {
        throw new Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException;
    }
});
```

You can enforce this filter on a route like this:

```
Route::post('register', array('before' => 'csrf', function( ) {
    return 'You gave a valid CSRF token!';
}));
```

See also: http://laravel.com/docs/html#csrf-protection

Comment: Thank you, im rather new to Token's so I will look into your answer, ive also amended my question.